# How can I make one Bundle for all activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I use NavigationDrawer with activities. And all activities are extended by a root activity which implement NavigationDrawer and it's base functions. I have many different activities in which I want to saveInstanceState, I want to store data in Bundle.

Here is example:
I have activties A,B
I do some changes in A, than I startActivity(B)! I guess A saves it's state in some Bundle before starting B. I want to pass A's Bundle to B activity (how can i do that? that's the main question)

Now i am in B activity!
Finally i want to startActivity(A) with restored istance state.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new Bundle object and put in all of the data you want to send to Activity B.
Then when you create your intent, pass the bundle into it like this;

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("string_extra","Extra Data, String!")
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle_extra",bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then inside ActivityB, you can call this,

```
Bundle extraData = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle_extra");
```

Once you have your bundle, you can just grab your variables out of it inside ActivityB.

Comment: I want to implement it to saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState with my activitiews. I guess, I need to call saveInstanceState after creating new bundle like : A.saveInstanceState(bundle), and inside B i should wtite B.restireInstanceState(extraData). Am I right? Will it work correctly?

Comment: You can use the bundle to just save the state of ActivityA, so when you finish ActivityB and go back to A it will be restored. Is this what you're looking for? So do you need the bundle from Activity A sent to B, as well as being used in ActivityA for restoration?

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I have Activities A B C D E F... i want to switch between them and save instance state every time! So if i was on A (sometime) i when i switch from C to A i want to load A state before i switched from A. ;) Appoligise for my english!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want to send data between activities:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(B.class);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("myKey","MyValue");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And to retrieve that information from Activity B:

```
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: Thank you for tour answer! Same question to you! I want to implement bundle to saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState with my activities. I guess, I need to call saveInstanceState after creating new bundle like : A.saveInstanceState(bundle), and inside B i should wtite B.restireInstanceState(extraData). Am I right? Will it work correctly?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) You can override this method and put all of the relevant info you want to save there. Then, when your activity gets recreated you can recover it with the oncreate method.